# Focusing browser tab when a value within the page reaches a specific number

Tags: javascript, jquery, browser, browser-tab

I have a web page that refreshes constantly, where a span have a number that is changing (decreasing).

Is there a way using JS for example to automatically focus the browser tab containing the web page when that number reaches less than 10 so that the supervisor takes action before hitting 0 without knowing?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by `focus the browser tab`?

Comment: @void I mean when the supervisor is viewing another website in another tab, it switches to the given tab.

Comment: No you can not control the OS's browser in any way using javascript (except by using chrome extensions and stuff, which anyway wont work in your case). Still to grab attention you can change the title of the webpage to show the alert.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.

There's two possible solutions.

1. Browser extension. This will give you a lot more leeway and control.
2. And this has become a lot more popular is to change the favicon on the page to another one that looks like an alert. And changing the title too. Playing a sound is another cue to the user that something has happened.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the browser and the user’s settings, [`alert`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) might take the user to the tab that opened the alert. In other browsers `alert` might only change the tab icon to stand out.

Firefox gives the user the option to enable this behavior with a “Allow dialogs from example.com to take you to their tab” checkbox, unchecked by default:

[image: Firefox delayed alert example]

Chrome doesn’t give the user any such option, but does mark the tab with an orange indicator:

[image]

[image]

You can test your browser’s behavior by running this snippet and then switching to another tab:

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  alert('this is a delayed alert');
}, 3*1000);
```

Comment: I was in a website where an error message appeared dozens of times (an alert saying only "error :(" ). Usually it would display "prevent this page from creating additional dialogs", but instead it displayed "allow dialogs from ... to take you to their tab". Do you know why did this happen?

Comment: @Rodrigo Sorry, I don’t know. I suggest posting that as its own question on Stack Overflow so more people can see it.